# Vuetify: v-select get item AND another value from v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Vuetify3 newbie here.

I have a table which is filled with v-for for some models. Each row has a v-select that need to fire an event when changed. Something like this:

```
                <tr v-for="payout in payouts" :key="payout.id">

                    <td>{{ payout.username }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <v-select
                            v-model="payout.status"
                            @update:modelValue="changeStatus"
                            :items="['On', 'Off']"
                        >
                        </v-select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

If leave function in `@update:modelValue="changeStatus"` without any parameters, I can get access to selected value in one v-select.

**But how I can get selected `value` AND `id` of current row simultaneously?**

I was thinking about something like `@update:modelValue="changeStatus(item, payout.id)"`. But of course it doesn't work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `changeStatus` directly, I would wrap it in a callback which dispatch `update:modelValue` argument AND `payout.id`:

```html
<tr v-for="payout in payouts" :key="payout.id">
 <td>
  <v-select @update:modelValue="val => changeStatus(val, payout.id)">
 </td>
</tr>
```

I omitted some code to make it simpler to grasp.